# configuring pyramid_beaker to use with mysql

Tags: session, pyramid, beaker

i am using pyramid_beaker as session factory .I want to save session in mysql database.so i want to know how to configure that?
i have gone through this
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/
but it does not solve my problem.
it does not give clue where to write mysql username ,password etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyramid_beaker is a thin wrapper around beaker which can pull the settings from your INI file into beaker. Beaker [1] itself which contains docs on how to use its various backends. For example, if you're using the `beaker.ext.database` backend, then you should set `session.url = mysql://user:password@host:port/dbname` just like any other SQLAlchemy connection string.

[1] https://beaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#options-for-sessions-and-caching